# How to Parse or get Website's Content into Strings and have and Output?

Tags: html, parsing

It's been a week searching for possible answer to my problem, I am making a program that would get the content of a website... im having a hard time on it. Here's is my code..

`Dim xmlstring As String = "<TBODY><TR><TD>**20121123-034**</TD><TD><I class="ball">**3**</I>&nbsp;<I class="ball">**6**</I>&nbsp;<I class="ball">**6**</I>&nbsp;<I class="ball">**4**</I>&nbsp;<I class="ball">**7**</I></TD><TD>**2012-11-23 11:40**</TD></TR>
</TBODY>"`

Dim sr As New System.IO.StringReader(xmlstring)

Dim doc As New Xml.XmlDocument

```
    doc.LoadXml(xmlstring)
```

Dim reader As New Xml.XmlNodeReader(doc)

```
   While reader.Read

    Select Case reader.NodeType

       Case Xml.XmlNodeType.Element

    If reader.Name = "I" Then

    MessageBox.Show(reader.GetAttribute("ball"))

    RichTextBox2.Text = doc.InnerText

    Else

     MessageBox.Show("-__-")

    End If

    End Select
    End While
```

`
and this is some part the source of the site

```
<TBODY><TR><TD>**20121123-034**</TD><TD><I class="ball">**3**</I>&nbsp;<I class="ball">**6**</I>&nbsp;<I class="ball">**6**</I>&nbsp;<I class="ball">**4**</I>&nbsp;<I class="ball">**7**</I></TD><TD>**2012-11-23 11:40**</TD></TR>
```

The numbers in **bold** is the one that i wanted to have an output on a textbox or rich text box..

Code's above are working but it only works on the text that was on the declaration on "DIM XMLSTRING"..... i want it's source from a live website...

Thank you guys!

Comment: You might want to specify in your question what programming language you are using.

Comment: Sorry about that.. im using Visual Studio 2008 (vb.net)